# Rails/Rspec JSON integers being converted to strings when testing post call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec

I am testing a JSON request to our API, It will respond with JSON. 
It seems like all the integers within the JSON get converted to strings as we post them to the controller consider action.

### Controller

```
  def consider
    binding.pry # binding no# 2 used to check the params after post from test.
    if ParametersValidator.is_valid?(params)
      application_handler = ApplicationHandler.new(request_interactor)
      render json: application_handler.result
    else
      render json: ParametersValidator.failed_params(params).to_json
    end
  end
```

The `ParamaterValidator` validates the structure and types of data coming in.

### Test

```
render_views
let(:json) { JSON.parse(response.body) }
..
..

it 'returns the result in the correct format for the AUTOMATIC APPROVE decision' do
  automatic_approve_params = relative_json_file(relative_file('automatic_approve_params'))
  expected_approve_params = {
    "status" => "accepted",
    "automated" => true,
    "rate" => 6,
    "amount" => 30000,
    "term" => 10,
    "pre_approved_amount" => 2500,
    "comments" => ""
  }
  @request.headers['HTTP_X_AUTH_SIG'] = Rails.application.secrets['authorization']['token']
  request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/json'

  binding.pry  # binding no# 1 to inspect the params before post

  post :consider, automatic_approve_params, format: :json
  expect(json).to eq(expected_approve_params)
end
```

### Binding no#1

```
{
 "student_id"=>1,
 "age"=>22,
 "name"=>"John",
 "age_range"=>"22-25",
 "criminal_record"=>false,
 "declared_bankrupt"=>false,
 "declared_insolvent"=>false,
 "declared_sequestrated"=>false,
 "defaulted_on_loan"=>false,
 "post_study_salary"=>100000000,
 "first_nationality"=>"PL",
 "second_nationality"=>"",
 "citizenship"=>"PL",
}
```

### Binding no#2

```
{
 "student_id"=>"1",
 "age"=>"22",
 "name"=>"John",
 "age_range"=>"22-25",
 "criminal_record"=>false,
 "declared_bankrupt"=>false,
 "declared_insolvent"=>false,
 "declared_sequestrated"=>false,
 "defaulted_on_loan"=>false,
 "post_study_salary"=>"100000000",
 "first_nationality"=>"PL",
 "second_nationality"=>"",
 "citizenship"=>"PL",
}
```

The test log is showing that the request is

```
Processing by Api::V1::CreditApplicationsController#consider as JSON
```

Inspecting the request just before the post action you will see the params are fine, then in the controller before I run anything I inspect the params and they are all strings.

Using postman to test the API with the JSON works as expected but it seems that rspec when posting to the consider action will convert all the params to strings. I have read a few dozen posts that claim by adding `format: :json` to the post action it will remedy this, however I have had no such luck.

I am obviously doing something wrong but I have tried pretty much everything I know.

Comment: Aren't all http parameters and variables always sent as strings? How are you verifying with postman that they are coming in as Integers?

Comment: Found out that its being wrapped in a string and then parsed on the other end. I changed the above to a integration test and did some JSON magic and its working.

Comment: @TheLegend having this same issue, could you describe you solution a bit more please? Cheers.

Comment: @mecampbellsoup HannesBenson's answer was the solution. The actual cause of the strangeness is Rails magic under the cover. It will convert it to strings as `ActionController::Base` gets the params it sanitises it to be generally safe.

Comment: @TheLegend yea, one thing you didn't mention in OP is that your specs are RSpec controller specs (right?) as opposed to feature/request specs. That I believe will change the params-casting behavior.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After replicating the issue you are having I managed to resolve it in a controller spec using the following:

`post :consider, automatic_approve_params.merge(format: :json)`

In my local tests I removed the
`request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/json'` and it still worked as you expect it to. Hope it helps.

Comment: In Rails 5, use `as: :json` instead of `format: :json`, e.g.
`post :consider, params: automatic_approve_params, as: :json
`

Comment: @RichKuzsma please add your comment as a separate answer!

Answer (score 21):

In Rails 5, use `as: :json` instead of `format: :json`, e.g. `post :consider, params: automatic_approve_params, as: :json`

Answer (score 1):

We can try this

```
post 'orders.json', JSON.dump(order: {boolean: true, integer: 123}), "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"
```

Comment: This seems to nest the params inside a 2nd group of {} and with backslashes and quotes in it.  How to just send what we wrote, ("mykey : 5), in the lowest level of the params hash without any added formatting into strings, etc?

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me and after a lot of tries, I found the solution to this issue. If you pass the `params` converted with `to_json` and pass `'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'` as env, `integer` will be passed as is to the controllers.

```rb
let(:params) do
  {
    down_payment: 10_000,
    asking_price: 100_000,
    payment_schedule: 'weekly',
    amortization_period: 5
  }
end

it 'works' do
  post '/', params.to_json, 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
end
```

This will work as expected.